# PHP's file_put_contents is suddenly acting strange and not saving a file?

Tags: php

I think this is a server issue because the same code works fine on other servers. I am using PHP8.1.

What has changed is that I could previously do this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("bla.gif");
file_put_contents("newfile.gif", $data):
```

This would created newfile.gif and store the data there. However, since this morning, I get an error:

```
file_put_contents(newfile.gif): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

To fix it, I did this:

```
touch("newfile.gif");
$data = file_get_contents("bla.gif");
file_put_contents("newfile.gif", $data):
```

Now it works perfectly. But this is bizarre, because file_put_contents should not require the file to exists. This has never been a requirement?

Is there perhaps some obscure setting I am not aware of or anything else you can think of that can cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Some sort of permission issue perhaps, that `touch` somehow magically fixes? What permissions on the directory does the user that PHP executes under, have? What are the actual permissions the file created by `touch` has gotten?

Comment: You are using relative paths: have you checked the root directory is correct? Did you also check the directory's permissions are correct?

Comment: Does `$fp = fopen("newfile.gif, 'w');fwrite($fp, $data);fclose($fp);` trigger a similar error?

Comment: No mention of `file_put_contents` in the 8.1 changelog: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#PHP_8_1